# Returning Resized Image from WebImage in RouteHandler

Tags: c#, image, ihttphandler, mvcroutehandler, webimage

I am routing my image and resizing them thru an imageRouteHandler.
Here is the code.

```
 public class ImageRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            var filePath="(from Request Context)"
            var image = new WebImage(filePath);
            image = image.Resize(width, height);
            image.Write();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error,

```
The route handler '...ImageRouteHandler' did not return an IHttpHandler from its GetHttpHandler() method.
```

the `WebImage.Write()` will write to the response as i know. What else is needed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
```

before `return null;` did the trick.